# " Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' " while installing phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I got " Access denied for user 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' " in the process of installing phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 16.04

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your permissions aren't set right for root user or you have lost your MySQL root password.

I would try resetting MySQL password for root and trying again. I guess this is the fastest way. Follow these steps

**step 1**

Stop the mysql demon with this command

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

**step 2**

Start the mysql demon process with following

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

(at this point it's safest to disable networking)

**step 3**

Start the mysql client with

```
mysql -u root
```

**step 4**

Then run following in mysql prompt, so you are able to change any password

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**step 5**

Then reset password with

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
```

**step 6**

In case you happen to have a mysql root account that can connect from everywhere, this is recommended

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpwd') WHERE User='root';
```

**step 7**

Once you receive a message indicating a succesful query, then run

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**step 8**

Stop mysql and relaunch it with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

I suppose you have these installed

web server apache

php

php_mysql support for apache

source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Comment: I belive Your tip is good so I accept  it. (but in a meantime i just press "ignore" from the last picture and login in the browser witch success)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using root as user try phpmyadmin as the user name.

I had a similar problem signing into my phpmyadmin login page using root as the user, and knowing the password was correct.

I had the same access denied for user root @ localhost every time tried logging into phpmyadmin, so when I tried phpmyadmin as user name! and the password I finally managed to log into phpmyadmin